# Superkey-Left-Drag for "move Window" on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 18.04, window-manager

At work I use 16.04 and at home 18.04.

I am willing to learn the new shurtcut (Superkey-Left-Drag) for "move window".

But switching between work and home confuses my until I upgrade at work.

I want **one** shortcut on both keyboards.

Is there a way to me Superkey-Left-Drag move the window on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: alt+mouse-drag should work in 16.04 and you can set the same combo in 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

On your Ubuntu 16.04, go to *System Parameter* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcut* and  just change in *Window* the shortcut of "Move window" with your shortcut

By default, this shortcut is **Alt** + **F7** on Ubuntu 16.04